# Knockout Nested Computed Property binds on page load but fails after Parent Computed Property update

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to create a menu where when you click on a button representing one of several groups, an image appears, showing the most popular product. I know this could be done simpler, but I am trying to work with an existing data model.

I am trying to bind an img element to a property (**ProductImageUrl**), which is a property of a nested ko.computed object(**MostPopularProduct**), which is a property of a parent ko.computed object (**SelectedGroup**).

```
viewModel.SelectedGroup().MostPopularProduct().ProductImageUrl
```

When the page loads, everything works as expected, data binding to the image works. However, when I click on the Group2 button, I get the following data binding error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: attr:{src: SelectedGroup().MostPopularProduct().ProductImageUrl}
Message: undefined is not a function VM133:3
```

The nested ko.computed Property MostPopularProduct() has a value and binds properly on page load, but after button click, after the parent Computed Property has updated, the nested ko.computed Property MostPopularProduct() is undefined.

I suspect the issue has to do with data binding of a viewModel property that is a property of a nested ko.computed property.

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/boaldave/n5KQr/9/

```
<div id="GroupSelector">
    <img data-bind="attr:{src: SelectedGroup().MostPopularProduct().ProductImageUrl}">

    <ul id="Menu" data-bind="foreach:Groups">
        <li>
            <button data-bind="click: $parent.HandleButtonClick">
                <span data-bind="text: $data.GroupName"></span>
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>

viewModel = {
    Groups: 
    [
        {
            GroupName:"Group1",
            MostPopularProductID: "Product1"
        },
        {
            GroupName:"Group2",
            MostPopularProductID: "Product2"
        }
    ],
    Products:
    [
        {
            ProductID: "Product1",
            ProductImageUrl: "http://placehold.it/100x100"
        },
        {
            ProductID: "Product2",
            ProductImageUrl: "http://placehold.it/200x200"
        }
    ]
};

// Since the data model above comes from a database, I extend the 
// viewModel properties with ko.observable and ko.computed properties:

viewModel.SelectedGroupName = ko.observable("Group1");

viewModel.SelectedGroup = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.Groups, function(item) {
        return item.GroupName === viewModel.SelectedGroupName();
        });
    }, viewModel);

viewModel.SelectedGroup().MostPopularProduct = ko.computed(function ()  {
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.Products, function (item) {
        return item.ProductID === viewModel.SelectedGroup().MostPopularProductID;
        });
    }, viewModel);

viewModel.HandleButtonClick = function(s, e) {
    viewModel.SelectedGroupName(s.GroupName);
};

var groupSelectorDiv = document.getElementById('GroupSelector');
if (groupSelectorDiv) {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, groupSelectorDiv);
}

</script>
```

Comment: This line `viewModel.SelectedGroup().MostPopularProduct = ko.computed(function ()  {` only attaches a `MostPopularProduct` computed to "Group1" item in the `Groups` array. The second item doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jhmRc/

Try changing

```
viewModel.SelectedGroup().MostPopularProduct = ko.computed(function ()  {
```

to

```
viewModel.SelectedGroup.MostPopularProduct = ko.computed(function ()  {
```

and change this

```
<img data-bind="attr:{src: SelectedGroup().MostPopularProduct().ProductImageUrl>
```

to

```
<img data-bind="attr:{src: SelectedGroup.MostPopularProduct().ProductImageUrl}>
```

In your example you are assigning MostPopularProduct to the value of the computed, which is why it works on page load but not after the value changes.

The second way adds it to the computed object itself

Comment: I went to lunch, then came back, and thought to myself, I bet I am adding that nested MostPopularProduct computed property to the initial SelectedGroup object, so when it gets overwritten on click, the new SelectedGroup object doesn't know about the nested MostPopularProduct. Thank you for confirming my suspicion!

Comment: I corrected the jsfiddle so now it works.  Thank you Thunderducky!

Comment: Here is the actual jsfiddle I ended up with.  It allows data binding with the original markup as follows: <img data-bind="attr:{src: SelectedGroup().MostPopularProduct().ProductImageUrl}>   http://jsfiddle.net/boaldave/3Sk6Y/3/